# Issue with joins & where clause

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I have 3 tables, Action, ActionType and Member. I'm trying to print out a table showing the number of various ActionTypes in a specific status (property of the table Action) for a specific Member; basically getting one line for each ActionType, and one column for each status (Analysed (boolean), Todo (boolean), Done (boolean)).
So say we have 3 action types, the query should return a 3x3 grid.

Now I can easily do half of that by doing something like

```
select t.name, 
coalesce(sum(a.Analyzed), 0) as 'Analyzed',
coalesce(sum(a.Todo), 0) as 'Todo',
coalesce(sum(a.Done), 0) as 'Done'
from Action a
right join ActionType t on t.id = a.id_type_action
group by t.id
```

This works great. The issue arises when I try to add the condition on the Member table with either a join or a where condition. I can't seem to find the trick, either the condition doesn't filter the sum of my actions/action types, or it *does* filter them but only prints a line where at least one cell isn't 0 - while I want a 3x3 grid no matter what, even if it's full of 0's.

Sample Data:

```
ActionType : id, name
insert into ActionType(10, 'Type1')
insert into ActionType(20, 'Type1')
insert into ActionType(30, 'Type1')

Member : id, name
insert into Member(100, 'Alice')
insert into Member(200, 'Bob')

Action : id, action_type_id, member_id, analyzed, todo, done
insert into Action(1, 10, 100, 1, 0, 0);
insert into Action(2, 10, 100, 1, 0, 0);
insert into Action(3, 10, 200, 0, 1, 0);
```

Desired output *when filtered on Bob* (something along the lines of 'where member.name = 'Bob') :

```
ActionType Analysed Todo Done
Type1         0       1   0 
Type2         0       0   0  
Type3         0       0   0
```

Desired output *when filtered on Alice* (something along the lines of 'where member.name = 'Alice') :

```
ActionType Analysed Todo Done
Type1         2       0   0 
Type2         0       0   0  
Type3         0       0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by rewriting the `right join` to a `left join` (which I find easier to follow). Then, you can add another join to bring the `member` table while filtering on a given `name`:

```
select 
    t.name, 
    coalesce(sum(a.analyzed), 0) as analyzed,
    coalesce(sum(a.todo), 0) as todo,
    coalesce(sum(a.done), 0) as done
from actiontype t
inner join member m on m.name = 'Bob'
left join action a on a.id_type_action = t.id and a.member_id = m.id
group by t.id, t.name
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to filter the sums on Bob's actions only. The ouput of the first row is  (Type1, 2, 1, 0)   instead of (Type1, 0, 1, 0) .

Comment: @ChristopheSchutz: I changed the join logic a little. Please give it another try.

Comment: Now it filters properly, but arised the 2nd issue I've encountered already : I only get lines in my output for rows that aren't ONLY containing 0's, which is something I don't want. (the output doesn't include the lines for Type2 and Type3, since the inner join doesn't find matchings for those).